# Does Plutus support floating-point arithmetic for on-chain code?

Tags: plutus, on-chain

Plutus provides arithmetic functions for Integers through the modules `PlutusTx.Prelude` and `PlutusTx.Builtins`. Are there floating-point arithmetic functions which can be used on chain? If not, why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

My opinion would be that:

Floating point operations are typically resource-consuming and expensive to compute.

I mean, even 1 ADA had to be made a million Lovelace in order for the possibility to have fractional amount of ADA.

I'd suggest you follow the same approach

- Let the onchain code deal with Integer and carry-out floating point operations off-chain.

Answer (score 1):

I used before this for operate with some divisions between Integers and then to truncate to closes integer again.

https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-tx/html/PlutusTx-Ratio.html#t:Rational

Like this:

```
number1 = 10  
number2 = 3  
result = TxRatio.truncate ( TxRatio.unsafeRatio number1 number2)
```

I think its just too expensive to operate with them on chain, ill not recommend, but you can if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Floats are well known to be the wrong datatype for encoding anything resembling money, fixed points should be used for such purposes.

Encoding them by `Integer` (with some hardcoded number of fractional decimals) is prone to errors by mistake, so you better wrap it into custom `newtype`. That is actually what Plutus `Lovelace` datatype does.

I am not aware of implementation for full-featured `Decimal` datatype in Plutus, but they are usually can be avoided in smart-contract logic.